# Magento 2 Restore backup error: Invalid "rollback file"

Tags: magento2, backup

I have created backups through the web interface.

Now I am running the rollback command from command line, but I am getting an error like invalid `rollback file`.

What could be the reason for this and how I can fix this?

The command I have tried to execute is below:

```
php bin/magento setup:rollback -d 1530455588_db_after_site_responsive_1_july_18.sql

php bin/magento setup:rollback -c 1530454706_nomedia_backup_after_site_responsive_01_July_18.tgz -d 1530455588_db_after_site_responsive_1_july_18.sql
```

On running both commands I am getting the same error.